# Migration runs but RSpec still can't find the table

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Exactly trying to run Chapter 1 example from Paul Dix's book in here:

https://github.com/pauldix/service-oriented-design-with-ruby/tree/master/chapter_01

So I do a `bundle install` and it works fine.
Then I do a `rake db:migrate` and it works fine too, outputting like:

```
➜  chapter_01 git:(master) ✗ rake db:migrate
D, [2013-05-13T13:55:13.316178 #9154] DEBUG -- :    (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations"
I, [2013-05-13T13:55:13.316265 #9154]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateUsers (1)
```

Now I run a `rspec spec/service_spec.rb` and it gives me the following error mainly saying it can't fun the "Users" table.

```
 chapter_01 git:(master) ✗ rspec spec/service_spec.rb
D, [2013-05-13T13:57:16.893140 #9166] DEBUG -- : env: test
D, [2013-05-13T13:57:16.936232 #9166] DEBUG -- : db/test.sqlite3 database connection established...
/Users/BA018938/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:472:in `table_structure': Could not find table 'users' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

So what is going on? Can someone take a quick look and see if you can run this example from the GitHub?

Comment: Did you specify the test environment when migrating? E.g. `rake db:migrate SINATRA_ENV=test`

Comment: @zetetic : no I hadn't, was just following the commands in the ReadME of his GitHub project. There is a section "New Comments" that is similar to what you suggest, and that fixes it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to build out the test database. since by default migrations only run in your current environment (in your case, development).

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

```
  rake db:migrate

  rake db:test:load
```